# need help on a proof in Li-Nirenberg paper : "On Hopf lemma"

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I refer the reader to this paper by Li and Nirenberg : 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20327748/LiNirenberg.pdf

in page 4 while proving Corollary 1, authors constructed a function, $h(x,y)$ and concluded $h\leq 0$ in $\partial \Omega$.

(I am sorry if I am violating any guidelines of website by not giving any detail. Please let me know if it is so, I will add them)